# Correct usage of %s when inserting/updateing into a psql database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, insert-update

I want to insert values (a,b,c,d) into a database and if the triple (a,b,c) already exists, I want to update that row with the new value d. For the sake of speed I want to bulk insert. I am using the following query:

```
    query = """INSERT INTO table
                 (a, b, c, d)
                 VALUES (%(a)s, %(b)s, %(c)s, %(d)s)
                 ON CONFLICT (a, b, c)
                 DO UPDATE SET d = %(d)s"""            
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query, ((
            test_dict[line]['a'],
            test_dict[line]['b'],
            test_dict[line]['c'],
            test_dict[line]['d'])
            for line in test_dict))
```

Here *cur* is a cursor to the database and test_dict a dictionary.
However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character: '('
```

So if I alter the query to

```
query = """INSERT INTO table
                 (a, b, c, d)
                 VALUES %s"""
```

i don't get this error anymore, but I also don't know how to tell the code to update the value d in case of a conflict.

Comment: The arguments are positional, remove the names from the format string.

Comment: How do I then alter the line 
DO UPDATE SET d = %(d)s?
If I use DO UPDATE SET d = %s how will the program know which value to use for the update?

Comment: It uses them in order aka. positional.

Comment: `query = """INSERT INTO table
                 (a, b, c, d)
                 VALUES %s
                 ON CONFLICT (a, b, c)
                 DO UPDATE SET d = %s"""  `
gives me 
`ValueError: the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I then alter the line DO UPDATE SET d = %(d)s?

Tell PostgreSQL, not python, the value to update to:

```
DO UPDATE SET d = EXCLUDED.d
```

EXCLUDED is how you reference the row whose insertion was conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing named placeholders with positional parameters. You need to do something like:

```
query = """INSERT INTO table
                 (a, b, c, d)
                 VALUES (%(a)s, %(b)s, %(c)s, %(d)s)
                 ON CONFLICT (a, b, c)
                 DO UPDATE SET d = %(d)s"""            
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, query, test_dict)
```

This assumes test_dict is actually a list of dicts